# Cannot load TensorFlow Lite model on microcontroller

Tags: c++, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run a TensorFlow lite model on a microcontroller, namely on a [Sparkfun Edge](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15170) board, however I'm having some trouble loading the model to the device. Here are the steps I went through:

1. Trained my own model in TensorFlow 2.1 using the `tf.keras` API
2. Performed full integer quantization of weights and activations using the instructions provided on the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization_of_weights_and_activations). I'm not sure why, but it seems like I wasn't able to get a model with INT8 inputs and outputs even though I followed the instructions provided. In fact, here's what my model looks like after quantization:
   [image: input]
   As you can see, my model's input type is still `float32`, which becomes `int8` after flowing through the `Quantize` node. Similarly, I have a `Dequantize` node towards the output of the graph that does the exact opposite, namely it takes `int8` values and converts them back to `float32`, as shown below:
   [image]
   Though this is not how it was supposed to be (i.e. `int8` inputs and outputs *without* `Quantize` and `Dequantize` nodes), it's fine as long as I can get it to work
3. Edited [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/person_detection/main_functions.cc) (as well as some other files actually, but this one is the most important one), which is part of an [example application](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/person_detection) of an image classification model running on a Sparkfun Edge board and hosted in TensorFlow's GitHub repository (this application uses TensorFlow Lite's C++ API for use with microcontrollers). More specifically, I replaced the following code:

```cpp
static tflite::MicroOpResolver<3> micro_op_resolver;
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D,
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D());
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(tflite::BuiltinOperator_CONV_2D,
                             tflite::ops::micro::Register_CONV_2D());
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(tflite::BuiltinOperator_AVERAGE_POOL_2D,
                             tflite::ops::micro::Register_AVERAGE_POOL_2D());
```

with this:

```cpp
static tflite::MicroOpResolver<10> micro_op_resolver;

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D,
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D(),
    1,
    3
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_CONV_2D, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_CONV_2D(),
    1,
    3
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_AVERAGE_POOL_2D, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_AVERAGE_POOL_2D()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_ADD, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_ADD()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_SOFTMAX, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_SOFTMAX()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_FULLY_CONNECTED, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_FULLY_CONNECTED()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_QUANTIZE, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_QUANTIZE()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_DEQUANTIZE, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_DEQUANTIZE(),
    1,
    2
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_RELU, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_RELU()
);

micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(
    tflite::BuiltinOperator_RELU6, 
    tflite::ops::micro::Register_RELU6()
);
```

which essentially registers all the different layers that are included in my custom model.
Following the [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/person_detection#running-on-sparkfun-edge) provided for the Sparkfun Edge board, I managed to flash the application to the board, but when I run it, it outputs the following error:

```
Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'QUANTIZE' version '1'

Failed to get registration from op code  d

AllocateTensors() failed
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since the `QUANTIZE` operation gets registered with `micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(...)` (see the last code snippet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error using the last version of Tensorflow (and tf-nightly). I already have opened an issue as well as another user on the Tensorflow's Github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36914) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36943).

I also got the same error as you for 'QUANTIZE' when using 'MicroOpResolver'. You can try using 'AllOpsResolver', but you're likely to get the same problem as mentionned in the issues.

```
static tflite::ops::micro::AllOpsResolver resolver;
```

Comment: Surprisingly, it worked! I don't understand why, though.
By the way, I'm facing a different problem now: the interpreter gets stuck at some point while executing the layers, namely an "Add" layer. What's weird though, is that it doesn't get stuck at the first "Add", but rather at the fifth. If I try to make it skip the fifth add, it'll get stuck at the sixth, and so on. I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that replacing `MicroOpResolver` with `AllOpsResolver` means that less memory will be available for tensors allocation and things like that

Comment: So it worked by replacing 'MicroOpResolver' by 'AllOpsResolver' ? Interesting. I guess it depends on the network architecture and the layers you use. Did you update Tensorflow?
For your new problem, did you try running your model using Tensorflow lite on your computer to see if it also happens?

Comment: I trained my model using TensorFlow 2.1 installed via `pip`, whereas the various include files (and the TensorFlow Lite interpreter itself) in the C++ program that I deployed to the board come from a cloned version of TensorFlow's GitHub repository, version 2.1. I've tried running the model using TensorFlow Lite on my pc, and it works (it doesn't get stuck)